# Map iterator behavior after 'erase'ing

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I was writing this code below, and found this strange behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   map<int, string> map1;
   map1[1] = "Hello";
   map1[2] = "Hello1";
   map1[3] = "Hello2";
   map1[4] = "Hello3";
   map1[5] = "Hello4";

   map<int, string>::iterator it;

   for (it = map1.begin(); it != map1.end(); /*it++*/)
   {
      cout << "Enter: " << (int)(it->first) << endl;
      if (it->first == 3)
         map1.erase(it);
      it++;
      cout << "Exit: " << (int)(it->first) << endl;

   }

   return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
Enter: 1
Exit: 2
Enter: 2
Exit: 3
Enter: 3
Exit: 4
Enter: 4
Exit: 5
Enter: 5
Exit: 4
```

When I increment the iterator `it` only in the for loop (check the commented iterator), the output is as follows:

```
Enter: 1
Exit: 1
Enter: 2
Exit: 2
Enter: 3
Exit: 3
Enter: 4
Exit: 4
Enter: 5
Exit: 5
```

I am confused as to why in the first case, when I increment the iterator, it again points to the previous map element 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing an iterator to `map1.end()` produces an undefined result, and this is exactly what you do when running `it->first` in the cout in the last loop iteration.

In the first variant, you run `++it`, reaching `map1.end()`. Conceptually, `map1.end()` does not point to any element, and dereferencing it can provide any random outcome (including SEGFAULTs). In your case, it probably points to stale memory containing `4`.

In the second variant, you never get to dereference `map1.end()`, as the loop condition exits once you reach the end of the container. You always print out the same element within the loop.

Note also the answer above - erasing an element invalidates the iterator, so both variants are still invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate a little more? On the other hand, why does it work as expected, when I increment the iterator in the for loop itself?

Comment: On the second question - it works, since you never dereference an 'end()' iterator. Presumably, in the second variant, once you re-enable the increment within the loop, you remove the `++it` from the first version.

I'll elaborate the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions are undefined behaviour, the latter just appear to work.

In both cases, you increase an iterator that has been invalidated, 
See for example [iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) 
The latter behaves differently, because the 'enter' and 'exit' are printing the 
 same iterator

This is solved by the "iterate-erase" idiom, that all STL containers support

```
// C++11
auto iter = container.begin();
while( iter != container.end() )
{
    if( SomeCondition() )
        iter = container.erase(iter);
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

This is exactly why erase returns an iterator

Note that *associative* containers, such as `std::map` 
did not support this prior to C++11

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think an `iter++` is missing after `iter = container.erase(iter);` statement. 
In C++98, `std::map.erase()` returns void. So, we can have an alternate approach like:  `container.erase(iter++);` Am I right?

Comment: there is nothing missing in the given solution, `erase` returns a valid iterator to the item following the erased one (or end). The alternative approach works for containers where `erase` wont invalidate subsequent iterators, so it will work for `map` but not for `vector`